# ContactListener box2d cocos2d contacted body property

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision-detection, collision

I have Building CCNode

It's have property:

in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic) int testProperty;
```

in .mm file add **tag** and set property

```
[[GB2ShapeCache sharedShapeCache] addShapesWithFile:@"Objects.plist"];
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprite.png"];
[self addChild:batchNode];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprite.plist"];
sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", type]];
[batchNode addChild:sprite];
[sprite setTag:2];                 //SET TAG
[self setTestProperty:10];         //SET PROPERTY
...
```

Also is the ContactListener class
It's work correctly with this code and i'm detecting body by tag fine:

```
#import "ContactListener.h"
#import "Building.h"

void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

    Building *buildA = (Building *)bodyA->GetUserData();
    Building *buildB = (Building *)bodyB->GetUserData();
    if (buildA.tag == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Collision with building");
    }
}
```

PROBLEM:
I don understand how get property from ContactListener

I tried to get it so:

```
if (buildA.tag == 2) {
            NSLog(@"Collision with building");
            NSLog(@"testProperty == %i", buildA.testProperty);
        }
```

But **buildA.testProperty** not work, and get error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite testProperty]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x434af0'
```

If your can explain my please how get property from this class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create body, I set into user data sprite.

In the Building.h

```
body->SetUserData(self);
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
'-[CCSprite testProperty]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x434af0'
```

You store the CCSprite in userdata, not the Building object.

You set the tag like this, then of course checking for the correct tag works:

```
[sprite setTag:2];
```

But this is incorrect because user data is not a Building but a sprite:

```
Building *buildA = (Building *)bodyA->GetUserData();
```

I assume that Building inherits from CCSprite, this is why accessing the common properties like tag works, but not the Building specific properties.

Comment: Thank you weary match. I'm understood this until I was searching for an answer. But how i can get my Building in ContactListener? Building inherits **CCNode**: `@interface Building : CCNode
{
    b2Body *body;
    CCSprite *sprite;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode;
}
`